# Write to fifo file

Tags: objective-c, fifo, mkfifo

I've created a file by using `mkfifo /tmp/my.fifo`. I now want to write chars into the file (with Objective C) to be able to grab them by `tail -f /tmp/my.fifo`.
For some reason this does not work. The tail command only displays one character, and then stops output.

Objective C Code:

```
NSError *error = nil;

[buffer writeToFile:@"/tmp/my.fifo" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"Fail: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

The NSLog does not output anything. So from Objective C perspective theres obviously no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was simpler than I thought:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle=[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"/tmp/my.fifo"];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[buffer dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
```